# "startPos and length must be the same type" error when trying to add a column in a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, datetime-format, calculated-columns, azure-databricks

I have a .csv file that I'm trying to modify with Azure Databricks using Python.

The file has two columns `timeOfMeasurement` with the format `2021-01-04T07:07:45.098+0000` and `eventProcessedUtcTime` with the format `2021-01-04T07:07:45.6768856Z`. I want to add new columns with these strings formatted to datetime.

The following formatting works when I use single variables:

```
import datetime

# EventProcessedUtcTime
a = '2021-01-04T07:07:45.6768856Z'
x = datetime.datetime.strptime((a[:26]).strip(), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
print(x)
print(type(x))

# timeOfMeasurement
b = '2021-01-04T07:07:45.098+0000'
y = datetime.datetime.strptime((b[:23]).strip(), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
#y = (b[:23]).strip()
print(y)
print(type(y))
```

and creates the following output:

```
2021-01-04 07:07:45.676885
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
2021-01-04 07:07:45.098000
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

But when I'm trying to implement this for the whole dataframe

```
  import datetime  
  df = spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true', inferSchema='true').load('/mnt/data/values.csv')
  df_adjusted = (df.withColumn("timeOfMeasurementDatetime", datetime.datetime.strptime((df.timeOfMeasurement[:23]).strip(), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

I get an error saying:

> TypeError: startPos and length must be the same type. Got <class 'NoneType'> and <class 'int'>, respectively.

I have no idea what the problem is because I'm compleatly new to the whole subject and woud be really happy if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use PySpark functions for that instead of the using Python's built-in functions.  You have following possibilities:

- if your strings are in the ISO8601 time format, then you can just do the `.cast('timestamp')` on corresponding columns:

```py
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([('2021-01-04T07:07:45.098+0000',  
                                 '2021-01-04T07:07:45.6768856Z')], 
                               ['ts1','ts2'])
>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|ts1                         |ts2                         |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|2021-01-04T07:07:45.098+0000|2021-01-04T07:07:45.6768856Z|
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
>>> df.select(df.ts1.cast('timestamp'), df.ts2.cast('timestamp')).show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------+--------------------------+
|ts1                    |ts2                       |
+-----------------------+--------------------------+
|2021-01-04 08:07:45.098|2021-01-04 08:07:45.676885|
+-----------------------+--------------------------+
```

- if your strings have some custom format, you can use built-in functions like [to_timestamp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp), and provide format string.